# Javascript function each 3 seconds glitching

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

I am creating a project in html, css, and JavaScript and I'm testing out a piece of code where each each 3 seconds, a function will go out but the function inside my code isnt working. I can't seem to figure out why. Here is my current code:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">



<script>
function myFunction() {
  setInterval(function(){ 
function test()
}, 3000);
}
function test() {
console.log ("Hello")
}
</script>
```

The part of the code where the function test() is declared is where the code is glitching but I can't figure out why, does anybody know whats wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call `function test()` in the setInterval function, you just call `test()`

```js
function myFunction() {
function test() {
console.log ("Hello")
}
setInterval(() => {
    test();
}, 3000);
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
```